# How to print array so it doesn't go over what it store in C

Tags: c

sorry if my question sounds confused.
Here is my code

```
 void display_Item_At_Location(char in[][SIZE_OF_ARRAY])
{
    int loc;
    int i;
    printf("Which line would you like to display?\n");
    scanf("%d", &loc);

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
    {
            printf("%c", in[loc][i]);
    }

    return;
}
```

The first line of array should be "Go to School" but when I print it, it will be "Go to School?????????????????????????" How should it do so I only get "Go to School"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your strings are NULL-terminated, you could skip the `for` loop and just do:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", in[loc - 1]);
```

for a given value `loc` within index bounds (assuming `loc` value is 1-indexed).

Comment: thank you! One more question please. Should I use for loop to display whole array?

Comment: If you just want to print one string, then you don't need a loop. If you don't ask the user to specify the desired string index, then you could use a loop to print out all the strings, assuming you know in advance how many strings you need to loop through.

Comment: Hello, Thank you! You help me understand a lot. How about if I have 2d string, what should I do to print all of them? In this case do I need a loop?